# Error mapping api model array property to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, api

I'm having issues properly mapping an API model to a stored procedure. Inside the model, I have arrays of properties that have arrays of properties.

The Model Part

```csharp
public class AccidentalReportResponseModel
{
    public AccidentReportModel[] data { get; set; }
    public PaginationModel pagination { get; set; }
}

public class AccidentReportModel
{
    public ConditionalFieldStatement[] conditionalFieldSections { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAtTime { get; set; }
    public DocumentType documentType { get; set; }
    public Driver driver { get; set; }
    public Fields[] fields { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public Route route { get; set; }
    public RouteStop routeStop { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedAtTime { get; set; }
    public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }

}

public class Fields
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public BarcodeValue[] barcodeValue { get; set; }
    public DateTimeValue dateTimeValue { get; set; }
    public MultipleChoiceValue[] multipleChoiceValue { get; set; }
    public double numberValue { get; set; }
    public PhotoValue[] photoValue { get; set; }
    public ScannedDocumentValue[] scannedDocumentValue { get; set; }
    public SignatureValue signatureValue { get; set; }
    public string stringValue { get; set; }
}
```

The Code part on the service side

```csharp
var accidentDetail = db.sp_InsertAccidentRegister(accidentReportDetail.createdAtTime, accidentReportDetail.driver.name, Convert.ToInt32(accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue).toList(, null, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.value, null, null, null, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue,
                                null, null, null, null, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue,
                                accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, Convert.ToInt32(accidentReportDetail.fields.value.numberValue), accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, Convert.ToInt32(accidentReportDetail.fields.value.numberValue), Convert.ToInt32(accidentReportDetail.fields.value.numberValue), Convert.ToInt32(accidentReportDetail.fields.value.numberValue), accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected,
                                accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.value, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.value, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.value, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.value, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue,
                                accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.value, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue,
                                accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, null, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected,
                                accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected,
                                accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.multipleChoiceValue.selected, accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue, null, null, accidentReportDetail.documentType.id);
```

Every `accidentReportDetail.fields.value.stringValue` throws an error because on the model side `fields` is declared `public Fields[] fields { get; set; }` and it gives an error at the `[]` part.

I am fairly new to c# so any advice or article or youtubevideo is welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: Dramian, I think your error is caused because you are referencing .fields as the whole array, but you need to iterate through the items within the fields[] array. I would suggest, first to decide if you actually have multiple "fields" recorded against your accidentReportDetail. then if you do, use a List<Field> type instead of Field[] type. aka list/ collection vs array.

Comment: further, you do need to iterate and package your list or array of "fields". you would extend your Object Value to decide itself which property to return ( is it stringValue, Multiplechoicevalue, etc. ) and likely wrap that in a get property like "getActualValue". iterate through your fields and build your parameters:::: like foreach ( field item in accidentReportDetail ){ consolidated into "flattened list of values" by new flatValue( item.label, item.type, item.Value.getActualValue());} - psudo code, comment, not answer

Comment: a quick g search resulted in this youtube video on lists. I have not reviewed it in depth, but it looks like it should benefit you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iKD7bbz96I

Comment: thank you @ThisGuy for the feedback/help it is really appreciated it.